# I want top ten supplier on basis of balance

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am writing a query using rank function and want top 10 suppliers on the basis of their balance. Below is the query which is i am using.

```
SELECT VENDOR_NAME, Balance, RANK_MAX
FROM
(SELECT xsl.VENDOR_NAME , nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) Balance ,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY xsl.VENDOR_NAME ORDER BY xsl.DR  DESC) rank_max
FROM xxng_supp_ledger xsl
)
WHERE RANK_MAX < 10
```

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: can you show as some sample table and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT tbl.VENDOR_NAME, tbl.Balance, tbl.RANK_MAX
FROM
(SELECT xsl.VENDOR_NAME , nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0) Balance ,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (nvl(xsl.DR , 0) - nvl(xsl.CR , 0))  DESC) rank_max
FROM xxng_supp_ledger xsl
) tbl
WHERE tbl.RANK_MAX < 11
```